# Should.js not finding object in array

Tags: mocha.js, should.js

I'm writing tests to validate what an async process has written to mongo and I'm having issues with should.include to verify that a record is included. To simplify it, my projection only includes a single field (ag_status) and I receive the following error from should:

```
  1) Agriculture record should return at least one record with ag_status to true:
     Uncaught AssertionError: expected [ { ag_status: true },
  { ag_status: true },
  { ag_status: true },
  { ag_status: true },
  { ag_status: true },
  { ag_status: true } ] to include an object equal to { ag_status: true }
```

Here is the section of code that calls the should.include. I have tried chai, chai-fuzzy and chai-things, but none of them have worked (and do not give as detailed messages as should) so I am stuck right now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    it('Agriculture record should return at least one record with ag_status to true', function(done){
            MobAgriculture.model.find({ time_id: "AYearAgo" }, {_id: 0, ag_status: 1 }, function(err, result) {
                    should.not.exist(err);
                    should.exist(result);
                    result.should.have.length(6);
                    console.log(result);
                    var level2 = { "ag_status" : true };
                    result.should.include(level2);
                    done();
                });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with should.js but I think you *should* be using [includeEql](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/#includeeqlobj) as you want to verify that an object equal to `level2` is present in the array, not that level2 itself is in there. From their [docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/):

> include(obj)
>
> Assert that the given obj is present via indexOf(), so this works for
>   strings, arrays, or custom objects implementing indexOf.

---

> includeEql(obj)
>
> Assert that an object equal to the given obj is present in an Array:

Comment: That helps, but I am still getting the error. I added this: 
'var level2 = { ag_status: true };
[{ ag_status: true}, { ag_status: true }].should.includeEql(level2);
result.should.includeEql(level2);'
The first _should_ passes, but the second _should_ still fails. So, it is something with how mongoose is presenting it. But I cannot see anything wrong with it visibly. Any ideas?

Comment: @frankm I see you have a console.log statement in your example code, what's the output look like? If you copy the output from the log and test with that instead does it work?

Comment: the output is the top part of the original post, which starts with "1) Agriculture record...." I was trying to simplify the _should_ test case, so I changed the mongoose projection to just output '{ ag_status: true }'. So, my mongoose output array has 6 elements and each one is '{ ag_status: true }' and the variable I am searching for is '{ ag_status: true }'. In the meantime, I have reverted to sorting the mongoose results and calling 'result[x].should.include' for each _x_ element in the array, which is a fine workaround for now.

Comment: No longer in docs (perhaps this should be [`containEql`](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/#containeqlothervalue) now?)